# Find file and line of an elements CSS styles

Tags: javascript, php, css, parsing

Is it possible to get the files and lines of an elements css styles with javscript? 
Similar to how firbug or chromes inspector can tell you the file and line.

Or would I have to pass the element name and css classes server side and parse it there?

If its not possible in pure javascript any know of a php class that parses css files and returns line numbers of matching declarations?

I have looked at https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser and while its an excelent class, its not built to do what I want.

Comment: I know that you can do such things with javascript+jquery+PHP.

Comment: Did you search? Yes, JavaScript has an API for reading CSS. I wrote a two-part article on it some time ago - http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Dec/Being-Firebug-pt-reading-CSS-Javascript-194

Comment: Thanks for the post, very insightful. However, it does not explain how to get the line a rule is declared on. While I did do some research, I think my google foo was lacking as after reading your blog and doing another round of searching I found https://github.com/visionmedia/css-parse which can get the file/line for rules. However I have not impliemented it yet, but it seems like the way to go